# Tools are connecting to cursor

Tags: modeling, mesh, tools

I'm a beginner to blender and while working on my character I think I somehow messed up a few of the settings, one of them is that it won't allow me to use the tools normally and they all seem to be connected to the cursor, so for example if I try to rotate the jaw, I can't it only moves. I also can't scale or resize or anything. Can anyone help me?
[image]

Comment: Please add an image of Blender's complete window which you can create via the Window > Save screenshot menu. It sounds as if you have the Transform Pivot Point set to 3D Cursor in the middle of the header bar, but without seeing the whole screen it's difficult to say. (Default setting is Median Point.)